# Visual studio linking error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Following is the error i have after compiling my program

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'DSPatch.lib'

I am using VS 2013. The program works fine till compiling. Upon building, i receive this error.

I have header files and Cpp files and linked them using project properties but I could not able to find DSPatch.lib library anywhere. I am dying for help. Thanks in advance

Comment: If _you_ don't know where a file on your computer is, how is anyone else going to? o_O Did you actually build DSPatch or merely extract it?

Comment: I have extract the DSPatch zip file and didnt build it.